# reactphp - Undefined index

Tags: php

Estou Aprendendo `reactphp` e quando tento pagar a informação do banco de dadops da esse erro  `Undefined index` não sei o motivo

código q estou usando:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$server = stream_socket_server('tcp://127.0.0.1:8080');
stream_set_blocking($server, false);

$loop->addTimer(0.8, function () {
    include 'conect.php';
    $sql = "SELECT  `Msn` FROM `tss`";
    $execut=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($execut)){
        $msn = $row['Msn'];
        echo $msn . PHP_EOL;
        echo "<br>";
    }
});

$loop->addTimer(0.3, function () {
    include 'conect.php';
    $sql1 = "SELECT  `Usuario` FROM `tss`";
    $exe =mysqli_query($link,$sql1);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($exe)){
        $usu=$row['Usuario'];
        echo $usu;
    }

});

$loop->run();
?>
```

conecção com o banco:

```
<?php
$host ="localhost";
$usu="root";
$senha="";
$bd="ts";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $usu, $senha, $bd);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Falha ao conectar-se com o banco de dados MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já verificou qual é o valor de `$row`? Qual é?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss,  `$row['Msn']` que vem da coluna Msn, la tem o dado que era para trazer que seria `TESTE`

Comment: Ênfase no "era para trazer". A questão é: você verificou se o valor veio?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss dando um `var_export($row)` ele volta `array ( 0 => 'TESTE',)` Posso estar errado mais n era para ele voltar `0=>'Teste'` e sim `Msn=>'Teste` saberia me explicar pq ele esta voltando 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O motivo do erro e que vc esta colocando `mysqli_fetch_row` e o certo e `mysqli_fetch_array` ai ficaria assim

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$server = stream_socket_server('tcp://127.0.0.1:8080');
stream_set_blocking($server, false);

$loop->addTimer(0.8, function () {
    include 'conect.php';
    $sql = "SELECT  `Msn` FROM `tss`";
    $execut=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($execut)){
        $msn = $row['Msn'];
        echo $msn . PHP_EOL;
        echo "<br>";
    }
});

$loop->addTimer(0.3, function () {
    include 'conect.php';
    $sql1 = "SELECT  `Usuario` FROM `tss`";
    $exe =mysqli_query($link,$sql1);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exe)){
        $usu=$row['Usuario'];
        echo $usu;
    }

});

$loop->run();
?>
```